# How can I scatter outliers in boxplot created with matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, boxplot, outliers

I'm new here and very desperate. For my bachelor thesis I am doing some statistical analysis with matplotlib for the visualisation. My problem is, that I have a quite big data with lots of outliers where multiple can have the same value as you can see:

[image: curent boxplot]

Is there a possibility to scatter the outliers without displaying all datapoints (I accomplished that but had too many datapoints to show all of them)?

I wrote this function to create the figures:

```py
def draw_boxplots(axes, column_values, column_distinguishing_feature,  title, ylabel, ylim='auto'):

    '''
    :param axes: ax
    :param column_values: The column of the data frame, which contains the values to be plotted
    :param column_distinguishing_feature: The column of the data frame, which sorts the values
    :param title: The title for the figure
    :param ylabel: Labeling of the y-axis
    :return: This function can be used to plot multiple boxplots within one figure. It can be called after the
    'fig, ax = plt.subplots()' statement and provides everything to call the 'plt.show()' or 'fig.savefig()' statement.
    Further individually adjustments have to be done manually.
    '''
    max_out=[]
    max_main=[]
    list_of_group_names = list(column_distinguishing_feature.unique())
    list_of_group_values=[]
    cachedict={}
    for group in list_of_group_names:
        cachedict[group] = []
    for obs in list(range(len(list(column_values)))):
        cachedict[column_distinguishing_feature[obs]].append(column_values[obs])
    list_of_group_names.clear()
    for group in cachedict:
        list_of_group_values.append(cachedict[group])
        count = str(len(cachedict[group]))
        list_of_group_names.append(str(group) + ": " + str(count))

        print(group, ' Min:', min(cachedict[group]), ' Max:', max(cachedict[group]), ' Mean:', stat.mean(cachedict[group]), ' Median:', stat.median(cachedict[group]), ' Q1:', np.quantile(cachedict[group],0.25), ' Q3:', np.quantile(cachedict[group],0.25), ' Std:', np.std(cachedict[group]), ' Mode:', stat.mode(cachedict[group]))
        max_main.append(np.quantile(cachedict[group],0.75)+1.5*(np.quantile(cachedict[group],0.75)-np.quantile(cachedict[group],0.25)))
        max_out.append(max(cachedict[group]))

    wide=[]
    meanpointprops=dict(marker='D', markeredgecolor='black', markerfacecolor='firebrick')
    for group in list_of_group_names:
        wide.append(list(column_distinguishing_feature).count(group)/len(list(column_distinguishing_feature)))
    #, widths = wide
    axes.boxplot(list_of_group_values, sym="+", showmeans=True, meanline=False, meanprops=meanpointprops)
    axes.set_xticklabels(list_of_group_names, rotation=30)

    if ylim != "auto":
        axes.set_ylim(0, (max(max_main) + 0.25))
    else:
        axes.set_ylim(0, (max(max_out)-max(max_out)%100+100))

    axes.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    axes.set_title(title)
```

Thank you for your help!:)

Comment: Well, there are two things here. 1) Damn that's a lot of code and I'm pretty sure if I just cut and paste it in it won't work. This is why I'm sticking with the comments here. 2) More specific to your question, you want to look up jitter. Be warned, Matplotlib doesn't do this well, but Seaborn, which is built on top, does -- https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html?highlight=jitter#categorical-scatterplots

Comment: @hrokr Yes, you are right. It is a lot of code. I had some requirements to fulfil and I am new in programming, so it might be very confusing to others.. but I can ensure that it works 
Thank you for the seaborn tip

Comment: It's a lot in the sense that what you have isn't a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). An MRE is desirable for YOU because it gets you more answers. What I mean by not working is that -- for that much code in an MRE -- I'd expect I'd be able to copy it and run it. Instead, what you're implicitly asking is for us to provide everything that's missing so that an answer can be provided.